# IIS doesn't notice updated controller

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net-web-api, iisreset

On IIS 7 I have an application running which uses Entity Framework Web API.
When I copy and replace one of the `.cshtml` (HTML and JS) files in the Views folder, the change is applied instantly.

But when I replace one of the controllers, changes take no effect.

I restarted the IIS using the GUI, via `Run | IISReset` command and after this didn't work even restarted the computer. However, IIS still uses the old version of the controller.

How can I make IIS "recompile" the project and use the new controller version?

**Update**: Replacing the bin directory helped me out. Is there still another way to recompile directly on IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mvc is web application and precompile is available only on website projects

**Compilation**

**Web application projects**

- You explicitly compile the source code on the computer that is used
  for development or source control.
- By default, compilation of code files (excluding .aspx and .ascx
  files) produces a single assembly.

**Web site projects**

- The source code is typically compiled dynamically (automatically) by
  ASP.NET on the server the first time a request is received after the
  site has been installed or updated.
- You can precompile the site (compile in advance on a development
  computer or on the server). By default, compilation produces multiple
  assemblies.

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)